# Diverting users to a static Browser Not Supported page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, meteor, compatibility

At the moment I'm trying to build in my Meteor app a page to let the user know that their browser is not supported.

The problem is that my Meteor app doesn't even seem to load on IE6-9 at all. I just get a blank page.

What I'd like is that before it's all started, if I can direct them to just a static site telling them that their browser is unavailable.

This is what I have and it doesn't seem to be working

layout.html page

```
<template name="layout">

{{#if isOldBrowser }}
    {{> upgradeBrowser}}
{{else}}
<div class="{{iif currentUser 'padded' 'padded-top'}}">
    {{#unless getConfigSetting 'showLandingPageOnly' false}}
    {{> layoutNavbar }}
    {{> layoutConnectionStatus }}
    {{/unless}}
    {{> loginDialog }}
    {{> feedbackDialog }}
    {{> teamNameDialog }}
    {{> teamTimeDialog }}
    {{> teamAddParticipantDialog }}
    {{> teamEditParticipantDialog }}
    {{yield}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

My global handlebars

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'isOldBrowser', () ->
    BrowserDetect.browser == 'Explorer' && BrowserDetect.version < 10
```

My upgradeBrowser template

```
    <template name="upgradeBrowser">
<h1>Sorry mate! Your browser is a bit ancient! Try upgrading to <a href="www.google.com/chrome">Chrome</a></h1>
</template>
```

PS - i might also just mention that I'm only using the document mode setting in the developer tools built into IE11. It could so happen it might work but I really don't have any way to test it as I don't have an instance of an old version of IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drop in a third party package to handle that for you.

I could recommend either one of https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/redirect-ie-7-lower or https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/browser-detection There is also a device detection package https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/device-detection

That being said, browser/device detection has lots of problems. They can be misleading or even spoofed and the general consensus around meteor community is that you should be doing a more modern approach such as graceful degradation or incremental improvements through feature detection.

Have a read of this thread https://groups.google.com/d/topic/meteor-talk/ku7kvNJp8ek/discussion for different opinions.

Comment: i'm using the browser-detection package right now. The problem isn't that i can't detect the browser, it's more that I can't even get my Meteor app to load on IE6-9.

Comment: But i'll give the redirect-ie-7 a crack and see how i go

Comment: If your overall layout etc is having a hard time loading in IE<10, than your helper will not help. Try the window.location hack that comes with redirect-ie-7 package. This way you will just show a static html page. If you want to be able to load the general layout of your page but also include a warning, than your only choice is to fix whatever is causing your page to not load in the first place.

Comment: Hi, yes looks like the redirect package works! Now just gotta figure out how to redirect it for 9 or under instead of 7. I've looked at the code and see what they've done, but where would I put it in my app?

Comment: cause i think i need that bit to run before all the other mrt packages i have are run first

Comment: Put it in your lib folder, the deeper in the folder structure, the higher it is in code load order. Also you can make use of Meteor.startup(). Try changing the "7" to a "9" in the original package code.

Comment: cool yeah not quite working but I'll get there. thanks for your help! Spent hours on this!

Comment: I'm glad you have some progress now.